# selecting subsequent records arbitrarily with limit

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to do a query to retrieve the record immediately after a record for any given record, in a result set ordered by list. I do not understand how to make use of the limit keyword in sql syntax to do this.

I can use WHERE primarykey = number, but how will limiting the result help when I will only have one result?

How would I obtain the next record with an arbitrary primary key number?

I have an arbitrary primary key, and want to select the next one ordered by date.

Comment: How is your arbitrary primary key specified? Is this in a stored procedure or something?

Comment: Its an arbitrary primary key only because every key is unique, but there is no order to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be as simple as:

```
select *
from mytable
where datecolumn > (select datecolumn from mytable where id = @id)
order by datecolumn
limit 1
```

(Edited after comments)

Comment: I have an arbitrary primary key, and want to select the next one ordered by date, so I dont think will work.

Comment: What if there are duplicates of datecolumn?

Comment: Right-- I'll just vote for your solution instead of editing mine:)

Answer (score 2):

This will emulate the `LEAD()` analytic function (i. e. select the next value for each row from the table)

```
SELECT  mo.id, mo.date,
        mi.id AS next_id, mi.date AS next_date
FROM    (
        SELECT mn.id, mn.date,
               (
               SELECT  id
               FROM    mytable mp
               WHERE   (mp.date, mp.id) > (mn.date, mn.id)
               ORDER BY
                       mp.date, mp.id
               LIMIT 1
               ) AS nid
        FROM   mytable mn
        ORDER BY
               date
        ) mo,
        mytable mi
WHERE mi.id = mo.nid
```

If you just want to select next row for a given ID, you may use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   (date, id) >
        (
        SELECT  date, id
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = @myid
        )
ORDER BY
        date, id
LIMIT 1
```

This will work most efficiently if you have an index on `(date, id)`

Comment: That looks crazy..is it really necessary to have 3 nested queries?

Comment: If you need only the next NID, you may get rid of the outermost query, just select NID. This query is fast, and disk space is pretty cheap now, so "long queries" does not mean "costly queries" :)

Comment: The second query here looks like pretty much exactly what you want (though I don't see why you bother retrieving `id` in the subquery except to break duplicates).

Comment: Yes, it's to handle duplicates. If there are two records with same datetime: (1, '2009-01-01') and (2, '2009-01-01'), and you pass 1 as @myid, then 2 will be never selected if you don't put an id into the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, if you're looking for the one after 34

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE primaryKey > 34 ORDER BY primaryKey LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have an arbitrary primary key, and want to select the next one ordered by date, so I dont think will work.